# If Date doesn't exist, get the next valid date

Tags: python, django, date, datetime

I am using Python's `datetime` lib to parse a date and create a datetime object from it.

`datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET['date'], '%d-%m-%Y').date()`

This works as long as a valid date is passed. I could use a `try` and `except` case to handle invalid dates, but would like to return the next valid date, as this is a `Django` `view` where a redirect would make sense.

How could I solve this?

Comment: What does "next valid date" mean? How would you determine the next valid date for a completely bogus input?

Comment: Hm... you are right. I just couldn't come up with an idea yesterday, but I think I could just do it by checking for some cases. Years below 2010 would have no relevance to me and I could just change it to 2010 or current year. A year > current year+1 to current year+1. Months that are "0" to January, Months > 12 to December. This would already solve my problem. for months and years. And I think I could also handle days with something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4945362/4758860