# I need to find the no of days of a certain month by taking month name as user input using python

Tags: python, user-input

By taking month name as user input we have to find the no of days that month consits.
If the month name is incorrect (like if the user did spelling mistake) we have to print "None".

Expected Output:

CASE - 1:
Input: January
Output: 31

CASE - 2:
Input: jule
Output: None

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: You can use calendar.monthrange directly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938429/how-do-we-determine-the-number-of-days-for-a-given-month-in-python

Comment: @TimVielhauer Only if you know the year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to handle leap years (i.e., in some years February might have 29 days), you can use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) module:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Optional


MONTH_INDEX_BY_MONTH_NAME = {
  'january': 1,
  'february': 2,
  'march': 3,
  'april': 4,
  'may': 5,
  'june': 6,
  'july': 7,
  'august': 8,
  'september': 9,
  'october': 10,
  'november': 11,
  'december': 12,
}


def get_days_of_month(month: str) -> Optional[int]:
  """Gets the number of days in a given month for current year."""
  month = month.lower()
  year = datetime.now().year
  if month in MONTH_INDEX_BY_MONTH_NAME:
    return calendar.monthrange(year, MONTH_INDEX_BY_MONTH_NAME[month])[1]
  return None


def main() -> None:
  user_input = input("Enter the name of the month: ")
  days = get_days_of_month(user_input)
  print(days)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Example Usage 1:**

```
Enter the name of the month: January
31
```

**Example Usage 2:**

```
Enter the name of the month: jule
None
```

**Example Usage 3:**

```
Enter the name of the month: February
28
```